# Users and Groups: 3 or 2 tables (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm wondering about the pros and cons of storing my users and their groups in 3 tables vs. 2 tables.

**Pros of 2 tables**

1. The groups could easily just be users themselves and would seem in most scenarios to share all the same fields as users, i.e., name, picture, password, email.

**Pros of 3 tables**

1. Having a 3rd `groups` table would be more explicit so this might be easier for developers to understand/maintain.

**Cons of 3 tables**
1. Violating DRY principles across application code by not doing the #1 in the "Pros of 2 tables" above.

What else should I be thinking of?

The 2 mandatory tables are a `users` table and a `group_member` table.

```
+---------+      +------------+
| users    |      | group_member |     +----------+
+---------+      +------------+     | groups    |
| user_id |----->| user_id    |     +----------+
| name    |      | group_id   |<----| group_id |
| pass    |      +------------+     | name     | 
| ...     |                         | ...      |
+---------+                         +----------+

                                    **theoretical 3rd table**
```

*note:* The `user_id` and the `group_id` in the `group_member` table would both be 
referring to the `user_id` in the `users` table

Comment: This totally depends on what you expect your application to do now and in the near future. Though I would tend to err on the side of normalization.

Comment: @MikeBrant Thanks, can you provide some examples, perhaps in an answer? Thinking about this subject is very new to me so I don't even know what's possible.

Comment: Marked as off-topic to be migrated to [dba.se]

Comment: @hjpotter92 lots of application code would have to be re-written so that's why I chose SO. The topic really cuts across many aspects of development, so DBA seemed to limited. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @MikeBrant what does "Though I would tend to err on the side of normalization" mean in this context? 3 tables or 2? To me, 2 tables seem to introduce less redundancy.

Comment: @timpeterson To properly normalize this data I would think you 3 tables, that is unless a user can only belong to a single group, in which case you could skip the `group_member` table and just put the users' group id in the `users` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main point: if you want to store users & groups in one table as they share (most) characteristics, this is perfectly valid. *However*, this would mean that technically a group can be a member of a user, and you can't enforce on a database level that users can be in groups and not the other wary around:

Scenario in 1 table:

```
CREATE TABLE users_and_groups (id int...
CREATE TABLE group_members (
    group_id, 
    user_id
    FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES users_and_group (id) -- no way to limit on only groups
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users_and_group (id) -- no way to limit on only users   
)
```

Scenario in 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id int...
CREATE TABLE groups (id int...
CREATE TABLE group_members (
    group_id, 
    user_id
    FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES groups (id) -- guarantees a group
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)   -- guarantees a user
)
```

Setting up a database defensively like this can prevent a whole lot of hurt if bugs at the application level arise.

---

If however, the `user` & `group` entities share a *lot* of data (can both own other objects for instance, have profile pages, etc.), a 4 table solution can work out well:

```
CREATE TABLE users_and_groups (id, ...shared data...
CREATE TABLE users (users_and_groups_id, ...user specific data...
CREATE TABLE groups (users_and_groups_id, .. group specific data...
CREATE TABLE group_members (
    group_id, 
    user_id
    FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES groups (users_and_groups_id) -- guarantees a group
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (users_and_groups_id)   -- guarantees a user
)
```

This has several advantages:

- foreign keys where either groups or users are allowd can be in 1 column.
- at the application level, this is classic inheritance: a base `users_and_groups`, and both `user` & `group` *extend* that base class/table.
- enforcing either a group or a user is still possible with foreign keys
- if users or groups get specific data, there is no need to add a column to a table which is useless for a large portion of the records, it can be stored in the type-specific tables.

Some disadvantages:

- it is impossible to enforce that an entity is either a user or a group, but not *both* or *none* (type-less)
- unless you store a redundant column `type` (or `is_group` / `is_user`), determining whether an entity is a group or a user requires a `JOIN`, but as this is on primary key on both sides, the overhead should be small

Comment: -@Wrikken, thanks. What about in the `users_and_groups` table simply having a boolean `is_group` field? I'm trying to weigh the cost in putative bugs you mention vs. having a single, auto-incremented primary key that identifies all accounts (users+groups). Would be seem ideal to have one number for each account.

Comment: You can add the `is_group`, but that doesn't change the fact you _still_ can't enforce integrity of the `group_members` table at that point. There is no syntax for `REFERENCES users_and_groups (id) WHERE is_group = 1`. What are the advantages specifically you think you can get from the single id?

Comment: There is another option, and it involves 4 tables, but _can_ under some circumstances work out quite nicely: `users_and_groups(id, ...shared data...), users (id_from_users_and_groups, ...specific user data ...), groups (id_from_users_and_groups, ...specific group data...), group_members (group_id, user_id, FOREIGN KEY group_id REFERENCES groups (id_from_users_and_groups), FOREIGN KEY user_id REFERENCES user (id_from_users_and_groups)`. Kind of like classes & inheritance: the `users` & `groups` each _extend_ the `users_and_groups` data, and you can still enforce integrity & keep your single id.

Comment: -@Wrikken "What are the advantages specifically you think you can get from the single id?"  In all other tables where there is a `user_id` (most of my ~25 tables), I will have to determine whether that id can also be a `group_id` and if so I will have to add a field to these tables to distinguish the two account types. Basically, it could be alot of application code and SQL code re-writing.

Comment: Valid use indeed. If currently users & groups share all data, you _could_ go with the 2 table solution and hope the application handles the group_members problem well. If you however now have some columns only for users, or only for groups, or imagine there will/might be in future, the 4 table solution offers a lot of flexibility this way, without the need to alter your existing tables to a group_id.

Comment: I like the 4 table solution best. I'll keep it in mind. Since my application hasn't launched yet, I think I'll just stick with the 2 tables and the split the user/group-specific data if that ever makes sense. Feel free to add the 4 table solution to your answer (I can do it too) and I'll accept it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If anything, I think `group_member` would be the optional table.  You'd *only* want this table if you needed a *many-to-many* relationship between *users* and *groups*.  In other words, if a user can belong to more than one group, you'd want a table that can link a `user_id` to a `group_id`.  If a *user* can only belong to *one* group, you'd probably *still* want a `groups` table, and then have a `group_id` column on the `users` table.

But, to answer your original question, if you stored the group information (such as the group name) in the `group_member` table, you'd have to repeat this data for each user within the group.  You'd have many rows that have the same group name, and if you wanted to then *change* a group name later, you'd have to update many rows rather than just one.  It also makes it very difficult to tell who's in the same group, and a lot of those sorts of queries would become very inefficient.

Normalizing your distinct groups into a single `groups` table is definitely the right approach, regardless of whether you use one or two tables.

Comment: -@MikeChristensen, thanks. What I'm thinking is that the group name would be stored in the user table because for a group the group_id=user_id. The group is itself a user. Does this change your view?

Comment: No, I'd still normalize the groups into their own table.  That way, you can store various metadata on the group and just link one or more users to those groups.  In relational databases, the rule is to minimize redundancy.